# TensorFlow-IO not working due to SO file error

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-io

Most operations of [TensorFlow-IO](https://www.tensorflow.org/io) cause an error indicating that the file "libtensorflow_io.so" cannot be opened from the specified location, even though I confirmed its existence.

For example, the following code reproduces the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf, tensorflow_io as tfio
file = tf.io.read_file("./songs/0.mp3")
tfio.audio.decode_mp3(file)
```

I also tried reinstalling the `tfio` package, but to no avail.

---

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 3
      1 import tensorflow as tf, tensorflow_io as tfio
      2 file = tf.io.read_file("./songs/0.mp3")
----> 3 tfio.audio.decode_mp3(file)

File c:\Users\Thijs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_io\python\ops\audio_ops.py:593, in decode_mp3(input, shape, name)
    591 if shape is None:
    592     shape = tf.constant([-1, -1], tf.int64)
--> 593 return core_ops.io_audio_decode_mp3(input, shape=shape, name=name)

File c:\Users\Thijs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_io\python\ops\__init__.py:88, in LazyLoader.__getattr__(self, attrb)
     87 def __getattr__(self, attrb):
---> 88     return getattr(self._load(), attrb)

File c:\Users\Thijs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_io\python\ops\__init__.py:84, in LazyLoader._load(self)
     82 def _load(self):
     83     if self._mod is None:
---> 84         self._mod = _load_library(self._library)
     85     return self._mod

File c:\Users\Thijs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_io\python\ops\__init__.py:69, in _load_library(filename, lib)
     67     except (tf.errors.NotFoundError, OSError) as e:
     68         errs.append(str(e))
---> 69 raise NotImplementedError(
     70     "unable to open file: "
     71     + f"{filename}, from paths: {filenames}\ncaused by: {errs}"
     72 )

NotImplementedError: unable to open file: libtensorflow_io.so, from paths: ['c:\\Users\\Thijs\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow_io\\python\\ops\\libtensorflow_io.so']
caused by: ['c:\\Users\\Thijs\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow_io\\python\\ops\\libtensorflow_io.so not found']
```